# reset effective uid to root fails

Tags: perl

I have a linux perl program that runs as root. It runs some DBD::Pg code which cannot run as root but runs as another user with ident authentication. I can't use password authentication or anything similar.

I switch to this other user using $>. The problem is that I need to return to root to continue processing. $>=$< then fails when I try to return to an effective uid of root. I assume this is simply because the non-root user doesn't have the authority to switch to root.

Can anyone suggest a reasonable alternative?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using? This works for me as root (prints "bin" then "root"): `perl -e '$> = 1; print qx(whoami); $> = $<; print qx(whoami)'`

Comment: You can't drop privileges and re-escalate them - that would be a security breach.

Answer (score 2):

I would fork the process. change the user in the child process.

```
my $pid = fork;
die "error with fork" unless defined $pid;
if ($pid) {
    waitpid($pid);
} else {
    $>=2;
    eval {
        print qx(whoami),"\n";
    };
    exit();
}
```